# How to disable snapd desktop notifications in KDE plasma (Kubuntu 22.04)?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, snap, plasma

I would like to disable the annoying desktop notifications from snapd (e.g. "Close the app to avoid disruptions") in KDE/Kubuntu 22.04 Plasma.

I have looked in the KDE notification system settings and do not see a way to do this. I have read it is possible under Gnome so I know it should be achievable in Plasma, but do not see how.

Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: No updates on this? I really like Ubuntu with KDE, but this notification is terrible

Comment: I agree. No update. :( I still don't have a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not a real solution, I'll post here my workaround, because it may help someone with this problem. At the time of writing, I'm running KDE Neon based on Ubuntu 22.04. Here is what you can do:

1. Set automatic snap updates to be less frequent and happen at more convenient time (the default schedule is `00:00~24:00/4` - four times every day):

   ```bash
   $ sudo snap set system refresh.timer=mon,21:00
   ```
2. Create a script at `~/.local/bin/snupd` that allows you to manually call the update whenever you're ready, with the following content

   ```bash
   #!/usr/bin/env bash

   sudo snap refresh

   LANG=en_US.UTF-8 snap list --all | awk '/disabled/{print $1, $3}' |
       while read snapname revision; do
           sudo snap remove "$snapname" --revision="$revision"
       done
   ```

   It also removes all the cached older versions of the installed snaps (you can skip this if you don't want to do it)
3. Make the script executable:

   ```bash
   $ chmod +x ~/.local/bin/snupd
   ```
4. Now whenever you need to update all the snaps, just open the terminal and run this:

   ```bash
   $ snupd
   ```

Comment: Thanks! I like your solution and will try it out. I am going to keep the question open for now, but this may be the best we can do. :)